# Testing AngularJS Directive with Karma & Dynamic Template URL

Tags: angularjs, django, karma-runner

I'm attempting to build a unit test on my AngularJS directive, but I've run into a few snags rendering the template. Specifically, my directive's `templateUrl` has a referenced to `window.STATIC_URL`, which changes depending on if the environment is production or staging. When running Karma tests, I receive the error:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET undefinedjs/templates/myfolder/mytemplate.html`. Here's the directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    ...
    templateUrl: window.STATIC_URL + 'js/templates/myfolder/mytemplate.html'
});
```

I'm using ng-html2js to preprocess all HTML files. Here's the karma config:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'build/lib.min.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'js/*.js',
    'js/**/*.js',
    'js/templates/**/*.html',
    'tests/*Spec.js'
],


preprocessors: {
  'js/templates/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  // setting this option will create only a single module that contains templates
  // from all the files, so you can load them all with module('templates')

  moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

The test runs `var element = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($rootScope);`. I have injected compile, rootScope, as well as the httpBackend into my test.

Additionally, the templates are loaded before the injector:

```
beforeEach(module('my-app'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('templates'));
```

**Why I'm relying on window.STATIC_URL**

This was my best guess for how to inject a changing variable into my Angular app. That variable is set by Django's STATIC_URL variable in settings.py. It points to my S3 path in production, and my local path in development.

**What I've Tried**

Since the directive being called relies on `window.STATIC_URL`, I've attempted to edit the STATIC_URL from within my test. (ie., `window.STATIC_URL = '/static'`) This doesn't seem to be working.

The only thing that seems to work is to remove the variable from the directive's templateUrl, and replace it with the static URL for the environment I'm testing in. However, that's not ideal, as I want it to change depending on the app. I'm fine explicitly setting the STATIC_URL from within the test, but not the Angular app.

I'm out of ideas at this point. If anyone has run into something similar, I'd appreciate the help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've taken this approach to using dynamic template urls in my directives:

```
<div data-your-directive data-template-url="'partials/other.html'"></div>
```

passing the url as an optional attribute that will override the default if provided. Within my directive I then have:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('yourDirective', [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function($element, $attrs) {
            // Default template path.
            var templateUrl = 'partials/default.html';

            // Check if a template url attribute has been passed in to the 
            // directive. If one has been provided then make use of this
            // rather than the default.
            if ($attrs.templateUrl !== undefined) {
                templateUrl = $attrs.templateUrl;
            }

            return templateUrl;
        }
    };
}]);
```

This approach may prove to be easier for you to test.

Comment: Thanks for that idea! Too bad there isn't a more catch all solution.